# How does this reduce + lambda list filter function work?

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I saw the following code to filter a list into two classes:

```
reduce(lambda(a,b),c: (a+[c],b) if c > 60 else (a,b + [c]), [49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90],([],[]))
```

How does it work? the `([], [])` looks initializing the `(a, b)` in lambda, but how does it work step by step?

This also doesn't seem to be working in Python 3. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

> How does it work? the `([], [])` looks initializing the `(a, b)` in lambda, but how does it work step by step?

At each point, the reduce sees a left hand operand, `(a, b)`, which is a pair of lists (initially two empty lists), and an element `c`. It adds the list `[c]` to either `a` or `b`, depending on whether it's larger than 60, and returns the new pair of lists. Thus, it will eventually return the pair of the elements larger than 60, and less than 60, respectively.

> This also doesn't seem to be working in Python 3. Why is that?

In Python3 you can't anymore define a function explicitly taking a tuple - [tuple unpacking has been removed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). So

```
def foo((a, b)):
    ...
```

is illegal in Python3. This is the problem here as well (except in the form of a lambda).

Comment: Python3: `reduce(lambda a,c: (a[0]+[c],a[1]) if c > 60 else (a[0],a[1]+[c]), [49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90],([],[]))`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first query, the equivalent using for loop:

```
>>> c = [49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90]
>>> final = ([], [])
>>> for val in c:
...     if val > 60:
...             final[0].append(val)
...     else:
...             final[1].append(val)
... 
>>> final
([76, 82, 88, 90], [49, 58])
```

Equivalent in python3 is:

```
In [8]: import functools

In [9]: functools.reduce(lambda x,c: (x[0]+[c],x[1]) if c > 60 else (x[0],x[1] + [c]), [49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90],([],[]))
Out[9]: ([76, 82, 88, 90], [49, 58])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following experiment:

```
>>> reduce(lambda(a,b),c: (a+[c],b) if c > 60 else (a,b + [c]), [49],([],[]))
([], [49])
>>> reduce(lambda(a,b),c: (a+[c],b) if c > 60 else (a,b + [c]), [49,58],([],[]))
([], [49, 58])
>>> reduce(lambda(a,b),c: (a+[c],b) if c > 60 else (a,b + [c]), [49,58,76],([],[]))
([76], [49, 58])
>>> reduce(lambda(a,b),c: (a+[c],b) if c > 60 else (a,b + [c]), [49,58,76,82],([],[]))
([76, 82], [49, 58])
>>> reduce(lambda(a,b),c: (a+[c],b) if c > 60 else (a,b + [c]), [49,58,76,82,88,90],([],[]))
([76, 82, 88, 90], [49, 58])
```

Function `reduce` is described as follows:

```
reduce(...)
    reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

    Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
    from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
```

In our example, function is a lambda function with first argument as a 2-element tuple `(a,b)` and second argument as an integer `c` picked up from the list for processing. Since function produces a 2-element tuple of lists, it is initialized as `([], [])`. When processing starts, if the element is > 60, it is added to the first list of the tuple; else it is added to the second list of the tuple.

The syntax `a+[c]` is really the `extend` syntax of a list. We cannot do `a+c` since `a` is a list and `c` is an integer. Likewise, for `b+[c]`